# Failed at Laravel Mix script

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I'm having this error while running any of my Laravel Mix Scripts. There is no description of the error. It's just showing this. I also tried by removing the `node_modules` folder, removing `package-lock.json` and by running `npm run cache clean --force` but no luck

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ota@3.1.0 development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ota@3.1.0 development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\nabee\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-02T19_05_57_921Z-debug.log

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My `package.json` file is:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "name": "ota",
    "version": "3.1.0",
    "description": "OTA",
    "author": "mnb",
    "browserslist": [
        "last 2 version",
        "> 2%"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.19",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "rtlcss": "^3.2.0",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "xxxxx": "^1.0.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@chenfengyuan/datepicker": "^1.0.9",
        "@curiosityx/bootstrap-session-timeout": "^1.0.0",
        "admin-resources": "git+https://github.com/themesbrand/admin-resources.git#master",
        "apexcharts": "^3.26.3",
        "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta2",
        "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.9.0",
        "bootstrap-editable": "^1.0.1",
        "bootstrap-filestyle2": "^2.1.0",
        "bootstrap-maxlength": "^1.6.0",
        "bootstrap-rating": "0.0.1",
        "bootstrap-timepicker": "^0.5.2",
        "bootstrap-touchspin": "^4.2.5",
        "chance": "^1.1.3",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
        "datatables.net": "^1.10.23",
        "datatables.net-autofill": "^2.3.4",
        "datatables.net-autofill-bs4": "^2.3.4",
        "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.20",
        "datatables.net-buttons": "^1.4.2",
        "datatables.net-buttons-bs4": "^1.4.2",
        "datatables.net-keytable": "^2.3.2",
        "datatables.net-keytable-bs4": "^2.3.2",
        "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.2.1",
        "datatables.net-responsive-bs4": "^2.2.1",
        "datatables.net-select": "^1.2.5",
        "datatables.net-select-bs4": "^1.2.5",
        "dragula": "^3.7.2",
        "dropzone": "^5.7.2",
        "echarts": "^4.7.0",
        "flot-charts": "^0.8.3",
        "flot.curvedlines": "^1.1.1",
        "gmaps": "^0.4.24",
        "gulp-rtlcss": "^1.4.1",
        "inputmask": "^4.0.9",
        "ion-rangeslider": "^2.3.0",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "jquery-countdown": "^2.2.0",
        "jquery-knob": "^1.2.11",
        "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
        "jquery-steps": "^1.1.0",
        "jquery-validation": "^1.19.3",
        "jquery.easing": "^1.4.1",
        "jquery.flot.tooltip": "^0.9.0",
        "jquery.repeater": "^1.2.1",
        "jszip": "^3.2.2",
        "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
        "magnific-popup": "^1.1.0",
        "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2",
        "metismenu": "^3.0.4",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "node-waves": "^0.7.6",
        "npm-install-peers": "^1.2.2",
        "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
        "parsleyjs": "^2.9.1",
        "pdfmake": "^0.1.65",
        "select2": "^4.0.10",
        "simplebar": "^4.2.3",
        "spectrum-colorpicker2": "^2.0.5",
        "sweetalert2": "^10.10.4",
        "table-edits": "^0.0.3",
        "tinymce": "^5.0.16",
        "toastr": "^2.1.4",
        "tui-calendar": "^1.12.5",
        "tui-chart": "^3.8.0",
        "tui-date-picker": "^4.0.2",
        "tui-dom": "^3.0.0",
        "tui-time-picker": "^2.0.2",
        "webpack": "^5.38.1",
        "webpack-rtl-plugin": "^2.0.0"
    }
}
```

Please help me out. I've spent hours trying to resolve this issue with no luck at all

Comment: What version of Laravel Mix are you using?

Comment: I am using Laravel Mix v6.0.19

Comment: can you post your `webpack.mix.js` file?

Comment: Here it is: https://gist.github.com/Nabeel-Baig/c14f51ee1c54ad0360ba3887f2a6873e

Comment: Huge thing... first of all, you should only have `devDependecies` not `dependencies`, second, in your `webpack.mix.js` please, use template string instead of concatenating like `"something" + json.value + "/" + string.something`... take advantage of JS... third, you have a looooooot of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of outdated packages. Perhaps try upgrading them and see if the error persists or not. For example, update your package.json to the following and then run `npm install`.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "name": "ota",
    "version": "3.1.0",
    "description": "OTA",
    "author": "mnb",
    "browserslist": [
        "last 2 version",
        "> 2%"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@chenfengyuan/datepicker": "^1.0.10",
        "@curiosityx/bootstrap-session-timeout": "^1.0.0",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
        "admin-resources": "git+https://github.com/themesbrand/admin-resources.git#master",
        "apexcharts": "^3.27.2",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
        "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.9.0",
        "bootstrap-editable": "^1.0.1",
        "bootstrap-filestyle2": "^2.1.0",
        "bootstrap-maxlength": "^1.10.1",
        "bootstrap-rating": "0.0.1",
        "bootstrap-timepicker": "^0.5.2",
        "bootstrap-touchspin": "^4.3.0",
        "chance": "^1.1.7",
        "chart.js": "^3.4.1",
        "datatables.net": "^1.10.25",
        "datatables.net-autofill": "^2.3.9",
        "datatables.net-autofill-bs4": "^2.3.9",
        "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.25",
        "datatables.net-buttons": "^1.7.1",
        "datatables.net-buttons-bs4": "^1.7.1",
        "datatables.net-keytable": "^2.6.2",
        "datatables.net-keytable-bs4": "^2.6.2",
        "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.2.9",
        "datatables.net-responsive-bs4": "^2.2.9",
        "datatables.net-select": "^1.3.3",
        "datatables.net-select-bs4": "^1.3.3",
        "dragula": "^3.7.3",
        "dropzone": "^5.9.2",
        "echarts": "^5.1.2",
        "flot-charts": "^0.8.3",
        "flot.curvedlines": "^1.1.1",
        "gmaps": "^0.4.25",
        "gulp-rtlcss": "^1.4.2",
        "inputmask": "^5.0.6",
        "ion-rangeslider": "^2.3.1",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "jquery-countdown": "^2.2.0",
        "jquery-knob": "^1.2.11",
        "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
        "jquery-steps": "^1.1.0",
        "jquery-validation": "^1.19.3",
        "jquery.easing": "^1.4.1",
        "jquery.flot.tooltip": "^0.9.0",
        "jquery.repeater": "^1.2.1",
        "jszip": "^3.6.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.25",
        "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "magnific-popup": "^1.1.0",
        "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2",
        "metismenu": "^3.0.7",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "node-waves": "^0.7.6",
        "npm-install-peers": "^1.2.2",
        "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
        "parsleyjs": "^2.9.2",
        "pdfmake": "^0.2.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.3.5",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "rtlcss": "^3.3.0",
        "sass": "^1.35.2",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "select2": "^4.0.13",
        "simplebar": "^5.3.5",
        "spectrum-colorpicker2": "^2.0.8",
        "sweetalert2": "^11.0.19",
        "table-edits": "^0.0.3",
        "tinymce": "^5.8.2",
        "toastr": "^2.1.4",
        "tui-calendar": "^1.13.1",
        "tui-chart": "^3.11.3",
        "tui-date-picker": "^4.2.2",
        "tui-dom": "^3.0.0",
        "tui-time-picker": "^2.1.2",
        "webpack": "^5.45.1",
        "webpack-rtl-plugin": "^2.0.0",
        "xxxxx": "^1.0.3"
    }
}
```